# How can I install lua rocks from a manifest file?

Tags: luarocks

I come from a python background and I'm hoping to do something semantically equivalent to `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install a list of Python packages at the right version.

Is this achievable with `luarocks`?  If not, is there a way to hack this together on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system in Lua is a little different. There is a rockspec manifest file associated with every package. You can list your package dependencies here in this file and you can install then using

### "luarocks install name.rockspec".

For more details, visit [Luarocks](https://luarocks.org/about)

More on Rockspec format [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Rockspec-format)

Instruction for creating a package/rock [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Creating-a-rock)

Comment: Similar to requirements.txt, that would install all dependencies for rock "name". But unlike requirements.txt, it also installs rock "name".

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to install a list of dependencies from a file without worrying about Rockspec, you can also just use this three lines that read a file with the exact same format of a `requirements.txt` file for `pip` (`package==version`):

```sh
while read -r line ; do
    luarocks install $(echo $line | awk -F '==' '{print $1, $2}') 
done < lua_requirements.txt
```