# Equivalent of package.json/requirements.txt for luarocks?

Tags: lua, luarocks

Is there a file/format that I can save all the dependencies required for an application so that I can run `luarocks install` or something and reads all those dependencies and installs them in that directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install lua rocks from a manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000905/how-can-i-install-lua-rocks-from-a-manifest-file)